# X Position Constraint Not Updating Programmatically - Swift in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

I have set the following constraint programmatically on a UISwitch that was set as an IBOutlet:

```
func setConstraints {
    let leadingConstraintTimeSwitch1 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: timeSwitch, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: timeLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
    view.addConstraint(leadingConstraintTimeSwitch1)
```

Whenever I change the constant of this constraint, the X position of the switch remains the same. However, when I go to the Size Inspector of the switch and change its X value, the switch's position *does* update correctly, however I do not want to use the Size Inspector. How can I get the constraint set programmatically to override the X value in the Size Inspector? I have also added a constraint specifying the Y position of the switch (a bottom constraint), and this one *does* work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is not alot of information to go from in your description..

I normally add my constraints like so:

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: timeSwitch, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: timeLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 10).active = true
```

are `timeSwitch` and `timeLabel` part of the view hierarchy?

have you set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to false?

Are there any other constraints at play that could be affecting it?

Comment: `timeSwitch` and `timeLabel` are part of the view hierarchy, I have set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to false, and I have many other objects with constraints that work completely fine. I don't see how there would be any other constraints that could be affecting it. Like I said, in the Size Inspector when I change the X Value the switch changes to the position of that X Value, but the programmatic constraint won't override that. Thanks!

Comment: how are you changing the constant?

Comment: By changing the constant in the `let leadingConstraintTimeSwitch1 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: timeSwitch, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: timeLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)` @Scriptable

Comment: you should be updating it like leadingConstraintTimeSwitch1.constant = value, your not adding another are you?. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27869514/swift-update-constraint