# Blank space coming between keyboard and UIVew in iOS

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitextview, ios-autolayout, iqkeyboardmanager

I have a tab bar controller-based application and I am using `IQKeyboardManager` to handle form-like stuff.

[image: screenshot of blank space in IQKeyboardManager]

Step 1: Tab bar controller with bottom a `UITextView` inside a `UIView`. Check Image 1.

Step2: When I click on `UITextView`, the keyboard appears but a blank space is appearing due to the tab bar. I have tried to remove `IQKeyboardManager` but it still occurs, so it is confirmed that it is not the issue of `IQKeyboardManager`. It is an issue due to the tab bar controller.

How to remove that spacing?

Comment: Do you have any constraint between the keyboard and textfield?

Comment: @Nan no constraint between keyboard and textView.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct. The blank space is caused by the tab bar. Override the y position in the view by adding the additional space **when you receive keyboard should appear** and not in your viewDidLoad or any place else because it will then be hidden behind the tab bar. Then you need to set it back to normal by removing that added value when the user is finished using the keyboard. eg.

```
// Declaration
var tabBarHeight : CGFloat = 0.0
// viewDidLoad
tabBarHeight = tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.size.height
// When the user begins using the keyboard move the view containing the textfield
yourView.frame.origin.y = (tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.origin.y + tabBarHeight )
// When the user finishes using the keyboard
yourView.frame.origin.y = (tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.origin.y - tabBarHeight )
```

If you have constraints, you will need to adjust them. Good answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27870216/4008175

This answer will assist you in listening to when the keyboard has been activated and deactivated:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27087733/4008175

Good luck!

Comment: @HardikShah I adjusted my answers. You need to update the frame position of your textview's parent view. See the updated answer.